# PC not posting after sudden power cut

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

My PC 'died' after a power cut in my home, when I was still doing some rendering job with a heavy load on the GPU and the CPU. There seems to be smell coming from the motherboard although I'm not not sure if the power supply is also toast.

I'd just like to ask the possible damage a sudden power cut can have on a motherboard and what I could potentially do to recover my pc.

**specs:**
i5-10400
Gigabyte B460M Aorus Pro
Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x 8GB) DDR4 CL16 2666MHz
NVidia GTX-1660
Corsair CX550M

***Any help or advise would be appreciated!***

[Video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YttynudHiMn553Nu8) (here's a video showing what the motherboard is doing when I turn on the PSU, and no it won't turn on when I trigger the MB power switch.)

**UPDATE: The power supply still works. But motherboard won't post.**

Comment: A burning smell would (most likely) come from a power surge upon power restoration. I have see a power surge on startup fry a router. Can you remove the power supply from the computer?  If so, do that and put it a foot or so away. Then see if the burning smell is in the Power Supply or on the motherboard.

Comment: "Any help or advise would be appreciated!" - Take it to a professional.  "a smell is coming from the motherboard" is obviously a very bad sign.  The fact your machine doesn't turn on indicates at a minimum the Power Supply will need to be replaced.  Is there a chance your house was struck by lighting?  Even if you were to replace the PSU, you should take caution, powering it on for obvious reasons.

Comment: I've tried to unplug everything and retrying, now the motherboard is doing this. [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YttynudHiMn553Nu8). I do think the PSU is toast as the leds are probably the PSU delivery a tiny amount of power. However I do hope that the motherboard isn't broken but the smell is not the best sign. Also the smell only lasted for a few moments and I wasn't able to pinpoint where it came from. But for now, would it be better for me to get a new PSU and test the motherboard or a new motherboard?

Comment: Getting parts can be money poorly spent if you make a wrong decision on what  to get. A local repair shop will be better able to help you with this.

Comment: Yea but seeing what's happening in Sydney, Australia right now, won't have much hope finding a repair shop that's open. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Whats with all the deferring to "profesionals"... DIY FTW my man! I'd suggest those flashing lights are some sort of beepcode. Google it for your mobo make/model and you'll prob get a better idea or where the problem lies.  Unless you can see burn marks on the mobo or blown caps, etc... (check front/back), I'd bet on popped mosfets in the PSU. They tend to blowup under load with loss of supply. If you're game, unscrew the lid for a look - you might find blown fuses in there too. ONLY do this with it unplugged, and wait a while to let caps discharge, and dont touch anything less ye get zapped!

Comment: And when testing, use as few components as possible, to limit further damage. E.G. No mem/hdd - if working, the mobo bios/uefi will give you a beep code to let you know it's missing something. Then you can add components back in from there. Hopefully its just the PSU, and its always handy to spare lying about, so you'd hardly be wasting your money trying with a new PSU first. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion, I guess I'll try to get my hands on a new power supply somehow.